# What is a good online service for getting Mercedes Benz car history reports?

Tags: maintenance, mercedes-benz

I'm searching for a good and trusted service that provides car history reports (mainly for MB cars 1990+ models). I heard about these companies recently and I would like to know more about them. I'm going to make a subscription since I have a lot cars that I need to check the history of (accidents, condition, ...). I would also like to know the advantages and disadvantages, any advice are welcome. If anyone here is currently subscribed to one of these services, may I know what kind of information do they supply and what is the fee range?

Comment: Will an AutoCheck do for you? I can run multiple full reports for you for cheap, if you want to run one to see what info is on it I can do that free for ya. /shamelessplug

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it's not about how to repair a vehicle